# Using absolute locator coordinates in Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, locator

In this simplified code below, I'd like to display two plots within `Manipulate`, and use the `Locator` controltype to set the value of `x` relative to its position within the first plot only.  With the `Print[x]` command inserted it is obvious that the locator is using the coordinates of the entire graphics plane.

```
Manipulate[
 Print[x];
 GraphicsRow[{ListLinePlot[{x, {0, 0}}, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 2}}], 
   ListLinePlot[{x, {2, 2}}, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 2}}]}], {{x, {0, 0}, {2, 2}}, 
  ControlType -> Locator}]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just replace `GraphicsRow` to `Row`!

```
Manipulate[
 Row@{ListLinePlot[{x, {0, 0}}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 2}}, ImageSize -> 200], 
   ListLinePlot[{x, {2, 2}}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 2}}, ImageSize -> 200]}, 
 {{x, {0, 0}, {2, 2}}, Locator}]
```

[image]

Also instead of `ControlType -> Locator` you can use just `Locator`.

P.S. Does anybody know how to choose the second plot?

Comment: To choose the second plot, The only way I could figure out was to explicitly construct the `LocatorPane` around the second plot.  Otherwise it seems to automatically pick the first `Graphics` it finds.  E.g.: `Manipulate[
 Row@{Dynamic@
    ListLinePlot[{x, {0, 0}}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 2}}, 
     ImageSize -> 200], 
   LocatorPane[Dynamic@x, 
    Dynamic@ListLinePlot[{x, {2, 2}}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 2}}, 
      ImageSize -> 200]]}, {{x, {0, 0}, {2, 2}}, ControlType -> None}]`

Answer (score 3):

Using `LocatorPane` we can do this:

```
DynamicModule[{pt},
  GraphicsRow[{
    LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt], Dynamic@ListLinePlot[{{0, 0}, pt},
          PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 2}}]],
    Dynamic@ListLinePlot[{{2, 2}, pt}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 2}}]      
   }]]
```

[image: locators]